# create a function that returns an array strings rearranged as a palindrome

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, palindrome

I am trying to write a function which takes as input an array of strings with only lower case letters. Function returns an array of same strings but with each string has its letter rearranged such that it becomes a palindrome if possible, and if not then it returns -1.

```
public static Object buildPalin(String[] arrayOfStrings) 
{
    String[] palindrome = new String[arrayOfStrings.length];
    int offset = 0; 

    int charWithoutReflection = 0; 
    List<String> whole= Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings);
    String wholeString = String.join("", whole);

    for(int i=0; i< arrayOfStrings.length; i++) 
    { 
        if (arrayOfStrings[i] != "") 
        { 
            int currentCharPosition = wholeString.indexOf(arrayOfStrings[i], 
            i + 1); 

            if (currentCharPosition != -1)
            { 
                palindrome[offset] = arrayOfStrings[i]; 
                palindrome[palindrome.length - 1 - offset] = 
                arrayOfStrings[i]; 
                arrayOfStrings[currentCharPosition] = ""; 
                arrayOfStrings[i] = ""; 
            }
            else {
                if (charWithoutReflection > 0) 
                    return -1; 
                palindrome[palindrome.length/2] = arrayOfStrings[i]; 
                charWithoutReflection++; 
            }
            offset++; 
        }
    } 
    return palindrome;
   }
```

This function works fine for case when input array is like this 
     {"a", "b", "a"}
     {"a","b","c"} and so on.

but when i am having input like below:
     {"aba", "bb", "cac"} and like this that is array of strings it fails.

Any guidance or suggestion on this is helpful.

NOTE:
This is not a class assignment but its a question i was asked in interview.
I was able to come up with above solution but now i am trying to make it working for corner case as well. This will be helpful for future interviews.

==============================Updated code as per comment of Eric below=========

```
public static Object build(String[] arrayOfStrings) {
   String[] palindrome = new String[arrayOfStrings.length];
   int offset = 0; 
   int charWithoutReflection = 0; 
   List<String> whole= Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings);
   String wholeString = String.join("", whole);

   for(int i=0; i< arrayOfStrings.length; i++) 
   { 
      if (arrayOfStrings[i] != "") { 
        int currentCharPosition = wholeString.indexOf(arrayOfStrings[i], i + 
        1); 

        if (currentCharPosition != -1)
        { 
          palindrome[offset] = arrayOfStrings[i]; 
          palindrome[palindrome.length - 1 - offset] = arrayOfStrings[i]; 
          arrayOfStrings[currentCharPosition] = ""; 
          arrayOfStrings[i] = ""; 
        }
        else {
          if (charWithoutReflection > 0) 
          {
             System.out.println("failed case");
             return -1;
          }
          palindrome[palindrome.length/2] = arrayOfStrings[i]; 
          charWithoutReflection++; 
        }
        offset++; 
        }
    } 
    return palindrome;
  }

  // code from main function calling above function is:
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a[] = {"abb"};
    for ( int j = 0; j < a.length ; j++)
    {
      String[] tokens = a[j].split("");

      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString((Object[]) build(tokens)));    

    }
```

Produces wrong output as : ( for input [a,b,b]

[null, b, null]  instead of [b, a, b]

Comment: Your code can't possibly work for `{"a", "b", "a"} {"a","b","c"}`. That's a two dimensional array of `String`. Your method only takes a one dimensional array.

Comment: Or are those two different examples of input arrays that work? That would make sense.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom: yes two different example of arrays ( not two dimensional array). both are different inputs. Just wanted to show cases where it worked fine and for what case code is not working.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `wholeString` variable? If you're just trying to rearrange the letters of each input `String`, you don't ever need to see all of those `Strings` as one big `String`.

Answer (score 0):

For each `String`, turn it into a sorted `List` or array of characters. Then go through the list character by character, counting the number of occurrences of each character as you go. If the number (n) is odd, insert n occurrences of your character into the middle of the output `String`. If n is even, put n/2 at the start of your output `String` and n/2 at the end. If you encounter more than two characters that have an odd number of occurrences, you have to return -1. When you get to the end of the list, place the output `String` into an output array. And if you get all the way through, return that array.

```
public static Object build(String[] arrayOfStrings) {
    String[] palindrome = new String[arrayOfStrings.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++) {
    String currentString = arrayOfStrings[i];
    if (currentString.isEmpty()) {
        palindrome[i] = currentString;
    } else {
        char[] chars = Arrays.copyOf(currentString.toCharArray(),
            currentString.length() + 1);
        chars[currentString.length()] = Character.MAX_VALUE;
        Arrays.parallelSort(chars);

        char currentChar = chars[0];
        int count = 1;
        boolean foundOdd = false;
        String newString = "";
        for (int j = 1; j < chars.length; j++) {
            if (chars[j] == currentChar) {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (foundOdd) {
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                        newString = even(newString, currentChar, count);
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                        newString = even(newString, currentChar, count);
                    } else {
                        foundOdd = true;
                        newString = odd(newString, currentChar, count);
                    }
                }
                count = 1;
                currentChar = chars[j];
            }
        }
        palindrome[i] = newString;
        newString = "";
        }
    }
    return palindrome;
}

private static String even(String oldString, char currentChar, int count) {
    assert count % 2 == 0;
    int halfCount = count / 2;
    String occurrences = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < halfCount; i++) {
        occurrences += currentChar;
    }
    return occurrences + oldString + occurrences;
}

private static String odd(String oldString, char currentChar, int count) {
    assert count % 2 == 1;
    int length = oldString.length() / 2;
    String occurrences = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        occurrences += currentChar;
    }
    return oldString.substring(0, length) + occurrences
        + oldString.substring(length);
}

// code from main function calling above function is:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a[] = { "abb", "aaaabbcccddddeeffgghhii" };
    Object result = build(a);
    if (result.equals(-1)) {
        System.out.println("Failed to find a palindrome for at least one of the input values");
    } else {
        String[] resultStr = (String[]) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultStr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(resultStr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is horrible. It leans heavily on `String` concatenation, for one thing. But it works.

Comment: I tried making changes as per your suggestion but it fails for case when "abb", it produces output as ===>  [ null, b , null ]. Updated question with latest code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split your solution to two separate case the odd case and the even case. For both case do a count array of the frequency characters.

```
 First Case:
    1) Check that all chars have even count but one.
    2) Create a stringBuffer and append the odd char and decrement its count
    3) For each of the remaining characters form your palindrome by adding a char at the front and a char at the end of the string buffer.

 Second Case:
    1) Check that all chars have even counts.
    2) Create a string buffer
    3) For each of the remaining characters from your palindrome as case one.
```